# Kusto - Arithmetic expression cannot be carried-out between DateTime and String

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Below Query does not return result gives an error message -  Arithmetic expression cannot be carried-out between DateTime and StringBuffer

How do I solve this pls

````
| extend Time=format_datetime(Testtime,'yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s.fffffff') 
| facet by Time,Status,ID
| extend minutes = (now() - Time)/60
| project minutes, ID
| limit 1```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time` is of type `string`, and `now()` is of type `datetime`

- The operation `now() - Time` isn't supported, as the error message suggests: *Arithmetic expression cannot be carried-out between DateTime and StringBuffer*

It appears `Testtime` *is* of type `datetime`

- Did you intend to use `now() - Testtime` instead?

Comment: Thanks this worked for me without the time fornat and facet.

Answer (score 1):

The [facet operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/facetoperator) returns multiple tables, thus it cannot be followed by another operator.

Comment: I am actually recreating a Splunk query in Kusto. So In Splunk query I have fields to list down the fields before the eval operator.

Is there any altreate to list down the fields in Kusto

Splunk query 
```| fields Time, Status, ID```